# Locus of points Q such that the distance from P to Q is c times the distance from Q to L forms........?

Tags: geometry

> Let L be a line and P be a point in the plane. Let c be a constant less than 1. The set of points Q such that the distance from P to Q is c times
>   the distance from Q to L forms  ??

$D_{PQ}= C\times D_{QL}$

Comment: What are your thoughts? Have you tried drawing this for, say, $c = 2/3$, $L$ the $x$-axis, and $P$ the point $(0, 3)$ to make the arithmetic nice? If not, then it's not yet time for you to ask us to do so.

Comment: You can assume that $L$ is the X-axis, and $P=(0,a)$. Then if $Q=(x,y)$, then the distance $PQ=\sqrt{x^2+(y-a)^2}$ and the distance from $Q$ to $L$ is $y$. Therefore the equation becomes $\sqrt{x^2+(y-a)^2}=cy$. You can write it as $x^2+(1-c^2)y^2-2ay+a^2=0$. Now distinguish three cases $|c|<1$, $|c|=1$ and $|c|>1$. Complete the square of the part that depends on $y$ and you get the equations of hyperbolas, parabola and ellipse.

Comment: Have a look at this enlightening page: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicSectionDirectrix.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L:y=m;\;P(x_P,\;y_P);\;Q(x,\;y)$

Call $H$ the projection of $Q$ on the line $L$

$PQ=cQH$

translates in

$(x-x_P)^2+(y-y_P)^2=c^2 (y-m)^2$

Expand and collect $x$ and $y$

$x^2+\left(1-c^2\right) y^2-2 x_P x +y \left(2 c^2 m-2 y_P\right)x_P^2+y_P^2-c^2 m^2=0$

That is $x^2 + d^2 y^2 + a x + b y + c = 0$

The equation of an ellipse translated

Comment: Thank you very much sir , you always help me